# what is mockrepository

Tags: .net, design-patterns, mocking, repository

I want to simply know what is mockrepository and how it is created.
please also let me know the use of the above...
can i have the simple implementation of mock

Answer (score 1):

From the [`MockRepository`](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks/api/files/MockRepository-cs.html) page of Rhino Mocks:

> The MockRepository is the main interaction point with Rhino Mocks.
>
> Common usage pattern is to create the  on [SetUp] and then create mock objects using either  or  and setup expectations on the mock object(s) by callling their methods.  A call to  would move the mock object(s) to replay state, a call to  is made from the [TearDown] method.

There are also examples of usage on the page.

Comment: can i have the simple implementation of mock